# A high quality contribution but an annoying error is present in my published article

Tags: publications, journals, errors-erratum

I have recently published a journal article in the IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing (IEEE TGRS). I can confirm that my contribution in the journal article is really of high quality and has promising results. Even my (very reputable) university congratulated me for my contribution during my PhD defense last year.

A few days ago, I discovered an error in my article. This error is really very annoying to me. In my article, I wrote:

> The database contains 200 images. We removed "23 images of type X", "32 images of type Y" and "12 images of type Z", and so as a result, we use 128 images.

And I mentioned "128" all the time in all my experiments.

That fact is that all my results are really based on the number "128". But if you look back, the total should be 200 - 67  = 133  not 128. So I missed to say in the journal that we have also removed "5 images of type A". In this case the total will really be 128 as I mentioned in all my experiments.

All my results are correct and are really based on the number 128. But any reader can say "the total number of images must be 200 - 67 = 133 not 128, so how the author got 128!".

This is really awkward for me because I did this work in a very reputable university and I really wanted that everything to be perfect. I am really sad and I feel the failure and a bit like "Perhaps I don't deserve to be at this university".  What do you suggest me? should I contact the editor? Is it better to publish the correction online via ArXiv or HAL?

Comment: Does this have any relation to the conclusions of the paper?  If not, I think it's not worth thinking about.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No this does not change anything in the conclusion or the results, but it is really a very annoying error to me since all my results are based on the number 128. So any ready can start asking a lot of questions about that.

Comment: "I can confirm that my contribution in the journal article is really of high quality and has promising results. Even my (very reputable)" might win the award for most self aggrandizing statement on this site, that's quite and accomplishment you should be very...?

Comment: I expect even if anybody was obsessive enough to check the arithmetic, they would probably assume "200 images" meant "approximately 200 images" and just carry on reading. Unless your paper actually contains all 200 images, in the final analysis, *who cares* whether there were 128 or 133? (Apart from yourself, of course)

Comment: To me, the bigger issue wouldn't be the discrepancy in the number of images, but the fact that there might be an exclusion criteria ("type A") that wasn't mentioned at all. Depending on what that criteria was, how non-obvious it was, and how significantly it differed from types X, Y & Z, it may be worth it to publish an erratum simply to inform people hoping to replicate/extend your work that there's something additional they need to consider when selecting images. It would be that, rather than a numeric discrepancy, which would motivate my decision.

Comment: The enemy of good is better.

Comment: @R.M. great comment. Yes It is important to remove the images of type A from the database. But I think if someone needs to apply my work, he/she will probably discover that I forgot to say that and that is why I obtained 128 instead of 133. But yes I am afraid that someone repeats the same error in the future.

Comment: " Perhaps I don't deserve to be at this university". What do ". Come on! You even makes me think that's true :))

Comment: Does the TGRS have a standard for publishing errata? That would be the course to follow.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but just a remark: I think you matured in the past 2 years, and that reflects in the way you look at the outer form. The informal language will appeal more to younger people, like your younger self. It's not actually *bad;* it's less conformant. Think of it as a genuine expression of who you were back then. (Yes, sometimes it's somewhat embarrassing to see a picture of one's younger self, admitted ;-). )

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes I feel way more better now in writing than two years ago. Today, I feel not comfortable with informal syntax and I regret that I loved informal things during my PhD two years ago.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is probably best to do all of that. Contact the editor and ask if a correction can be published (letters to editor, ...). Put out a corrected version somewhere visible.

But also, don't obsess over it. Perfection is rarely attainable in an imperfect world with imperfect humans.

The sort of error you mention is very common, actually. Once you write something it is difficult for you to read it as incorrect. Often your mind "reads" what you think is supposed to be on the page rather than what is actually there. It is notoriously difficult for people to proofread their own work.

Ideally, the review process should have caught the inconsistency, but since it wasn't caught, others glossed over it also as immaterial to what your arguments are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will contact the editor to see whether he accepts or not. Do you think IEEE TGRS can accept to update their published articles?

Comment: @Christina They won't likely update the article itself (because of the typesetting involved) but they are very likely to publish what is variously called a "correction" or "corrigendum", a very small statement by you (just a sentence or two) correcting the error, which will be linked to from the article page. That correction will get its own DOI and so on. This is routine practice and nothing to worry about. Still worth doing though, not because of the discrepancy in the numbers, but as R.M. notes in another comment, effectively this arises from an otherwise unmentioned exclusion criterion.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Thank you for your comment. In fact I have contacted the editor but still didn't hear anything from him. I am afraid that he will not respond to my emails.

Comment: If you've done your part (due diligence) then don't worry about it.

Comment: Well said. I am atrociously bad at proofreading my own work even though I'm a decent proofreader for other people.

Comment: Do as Einstein did: publish a correction, he did so [several times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_publications_by_Albert_Einstein).

Comment: @DohnJoe I will become crazy one day because of my errors. And I think that is why Einstein was crazy:p

Comment: Crazy is good, for a certain value of crazy.

Comment: @Buffy lol exactly! btw the editor didn't find my error serious and so didn't accept a correction.

Answer (score 16):

Since the asker said the in comments that the error is not related to the conclusions or results of the paper, the proper thing is to find something more important to work on.  Unimportant errors do not need correction.  Almost all papers have them.

Comment: Unfortunately I am a picky person and I will try my best to correct this error :(

Comment: Also, unfortunately, it reflects badly on you if someone else publishes a correction. Best that it comes from you. And novices can be misled even by minor errors, though not in the present case, of course.

Comment: @Buffy Nobody will publish a correction for such a minor error. At worst, OP will receive an inquiring email from a reader who noticed this. But even that is unlikely.

Comment: @Buffy and Roland, Thank you for your comments. Do you think my error is really minor? what about if someone is reading my paper and starts asking a lot of questions about how I got 128? This is really awkward :-( I really feel now the failure.

Comment: Well, certainly not a failure. Yes, pretty inconsequential. It seems obvious from your description that you just left out a bit of explanation, rather than something that falsified a result. Relax. Have a culturally appropriate beverage of choice.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you. Yes I will do tonight!! Cheers.

Comment: Hmmm. The beverage? Pour me one too.

Comment: Agreed with the above. This is clearly a careless mistake and not something that affects the science. If you want to be sure, you could email the editor to highlight it, and see whether they want to do anything about it.

Comment: @Flyto  I also agree with you. The editor informed me that this is a minor error and does not require a correction.

Answer (score 7):

Eternal rule of professional book proof-readers: no matter how hard one tries, an error will always remain.

...and this comes from *Literature and Fiction*. Factor in the added complexity of scientific writing...

...In short, do obsess over going the extra mile to deliver and proofread a paper to perfection. But don't obsess over the error that will stare you with a smirk after, in the published document.

Admittedly it takes some effort and practice to adopt this mindset.